# confusing notion in Bayesian inference

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, dataset, sample, independence

My confusion is on the observed data $D$, I think for $D$, (1) it could be only one observation, and it could be multiple observation, correct? (2) when there are multiple observations, do we need to assume the multiple observation are independent? I have the confusion here since I referred some text book and wiki, but do not see it is always mentioned the multiple observations are independent. Want to confirm with the expert here, (3) when there are multiple observations and they are independent, then $P(D_1,D_2,...,D_n|w)$ = $P(D_1|w)*P(D_2|w)*...*P(D_n|w)$, correct?

The following material is reproduced from [Christopher Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387310738).

[image]

Comment: can you give the book name?

Comment: Sure @Xi'an, never did this before. you mean book name or something else?

Comment: @hxd1011, sure pattern recognition and machine learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Exchangeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables) is often interpreted as the Bayesian version of i.i.d assumption . In i.i.d assumption we assume that the parameter we are interested in exists in some meaningful sense and the data at hand (1 or $n$ observations does not matter ) were generated as independent trials conditional on the parameter .

Exchangeability  is the condition that the joint density of the data remains the same under re-ordering or re-labeling of the indices of the data , so if we assume for example a binomial model then  under exchangeability  two sequence of random variables , each with the same length $n$ and the same proportion of ones would be assigned the same probability only the number of ones matters not the location of the ones .
So that  the assumption of exchangeability  in Bayesian inference means we believe that the data are exchangeable then it is as if there is a parameter (say $\theta$) that derives a stochastic model generating the data **and** a density over $\theta$ that does not depend on the data , this density interpretable as a prior density  thus  **the existence of a prior density over a parameter is a  result of the exchangeability rather than an assumption**

**Edit based on Xi'an's comment :**

Some models allow for exchangeability and others do not .In the  hierarchical models also  we can not consider the entire sequence of data as being exchangeable instead the data within any given group might be considered exchangeable that means we condition on the group and that is so called conditional exchangeability

Comment: Thanks Bahgat for the reply and vote up. After reading your description, I think the answer to my 3 questions are, (1) could be either single or multiple observations, (2) observations are i.i.d. (3) the formula is correct, could you help to review and correct/confirm? Thanks again.

Comment: @LinMa Yes you are  right we assume i.i.d data generating process ,I've had also the same problem with Bayesian books notation , e.g using $\theta$ instead of $\Theta$ could refer to multiple parameters so just consider $\theta$ ( and $D$ in your case ) as container contains all parameters (data points ) of interest .

Comment: @Xi'an you are right , see edit

Comment: Thanks for the update Bahgat. Vote up and I think if we cannot assume `D` is i.i.d. then we should use the formula provided by @probabilityislogic to expand `P(D|w)`, correct?

Comment: @LinMa: I am surprised that you _accepted_ this answer it does not answer your question, but describes instead another notion, _exchangeability_, that is not mentioned or even considered in the excerpt you provided.

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an for the comment, my question is actually if in Bayes inferences, observed data `D` are independent or not, I think Bahgat and you answered quite well. Maybe I do not make myself understood in my original question?

Comment: The dependence structure in the data should not be dependent (!) on the type of inference one applies to this data, I think, as Bayesian and non-Bayesian methods start from the same statistical model $P(\mathfrak{D}|w)$. It is only when this model is uncertain that the two approaches differ, Bayesian solutions moving to a meta-model.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Xi'an. Actually I am not sure why Bayesian inference assume observed data are independent (or we call Exchangeability -- as mentioned by Bahgat, actually this is my original question why asking this question -- I read books/wikis about Bayesian inference, and not see independence mentioned very clearly), I think from the formula provided by probabilityislogic below, Bayesian inference could definitely works for scenarios when observed multiple observations (about `D`) are not independent, correct? Did I mis-read anything?

Comment: You are still confused: **Bayesian inference _does not_ assume observed dataare independent** It takes the model as given, with whatever dependence structure is assumed on the data and starts from there.

Answer (score 6):

Just on a technicality, the proper decomposition is:

$$P (D_1,...,D_n|w)=P(D_1|w)\times P (D_2|D_1 w)\times\dots P (D_n|D_1 D_2\dots D_{n-1}w) $$

This is always correct - but when assuming conditional independence, it simplifies to the expression you have in the OP.  Time series models are examples where you do not have conditional independence (eg auto-regressive or AR models).  Standard linear regression models are examples where you do have conditional independence.

Comment: BTW, probabilityislogic, trying to derive your formula from right side to left side, here is my process (using two variables D1 and D2), could you double check if it is correct (I mean my below calculation process does not assume i.i.d. of D1 and D2, correct)? Thanks. 
$P(D1|w)×P(D2|D1w)$=$[P(D1,w)/P(w)] * [P(D2, D1, w)/P(D1, w)]$
=$P(D2, D1, w)/P(w)$ = $P(D1, D2|w)$

Comment: Hi probabilityislogic, if you could comment on my above question/comment, it will be great.

Comment: @Lin Ma - that is correct.  And you can repeatedly apply this (say with $D2=A2A3$) to get more than two variables

Answer (score 3):

While the answer of [probabilityislogic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2392/probabilityislogic) is making the right point and is thus *the* answer so far, let me add that any dependence structure within a sample $\mathfrak{D}$ is achievable with the adequate probability model. Statistical inference is possible for such models if there is some degree of repeatability. For instance, assuming a Markov dependence as in the OP means that the conditional distribution of each datapoint given the previous one is the same for all indices. If one does not wish to make any assumption about the dependence structure of the sample $\mathfrak{D}$, this amounts to observing a single realisation of the vector $\mathfrak{D}$, with an unknown distribution for which inference based on $\mathfrak{D}$ only is impossible (or unreliable).